# LXDE - Menu icon and panel icon are different, how to fix?

Tags: 18.04, icons, lxde

Using 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04.3 with LXDE desktop and Numix Circle icons.

Certain applications appear to be using two different sets of icons.  An example is `google-earth-pro`. This screenshot shows the the icon that appears in the menu (green box) and the icon that appears in the panel for the running application (red box).  The panel icon also appears in the header bar of the application's window.

[image]

How does one determine which icon is being used for these two different purposes?  My goal is to make the icons consistent.

Edit per comment:

Some of the other affected applications

- NVIDIA X server settings

[image]

- Audacity

[image]

Comment: Could you please mention some other applications that misbehave similarly?

Comment: @DKBose will do. Thanks. Will take me a bit to find one.

Comment: Of the applications you mentioned, I looked at Audacity in Lubuntu 18.04. Its icon in `lxpanel` and in `/usr/share/applications` match when I use the Lubuntu icon theme but not when I use something called Papirus. Re. the half white / half blue icon, from my time with pure Openbox, I remember that certain applications or dialogue windows of some applications would produce this "generic" icon. Sorry I can't be of more help but maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/how-to-assign-an-icon-to-a-program-in-openbox) could be useful?

Comment: @DKBose thanks for your comment. I looked into this a little more and it appears that there may be some "built-in" icons in the programs that aren't changed when one changes the icon theme. It seems that the icon in the program window frame always matches the one in the panel, but not necessarily the one loaded in from the icon set.  Thanks again and I'll pursue the link you offered up.

Comment: The icon theme you mention doesn't seem to be included in the default 18.04 repos. It's in 19.10 & 20.04. Anyway, at the bottom of [this github page](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-circle) there's mention of a hardcode-fixer script. Would that be relevant?

Comment: I added the icons from a ppa; not on a good device so can't check but ISTR it's owned by Numix themselves. Thanks for the additional link, I'll look at it in the morning.